# aws sdk dynamodb scan operation with FilterExpression(contains) is resulting empty items

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am trying to fetch data from AWS Dynamo DB scan with contains FilterExpression .I am using the following param but **receiving empty response as**:

{"Items":[],"Count":0,"ScannedCount":792,"LastEvaluatedKey":{"ID":"b123456789"}}"}

where i want to filter based on string from array ex: orange from fruits:['orange', 'apple', 'banana'];

**Param for scan operation:**

params = {
TableName: table,
FilterExpression: "contains (fruits, :L)",
ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":L": { S :"orange" } }
}

but when i use the same as command of AWS CLI. I am getting data in following format :

{"Items": [{"fruits": {"L": [{"S": "orange"}]}},{}]}

Can you please let me know what is wrong with the param i am using.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is happening here, you need to understand how DynamoDB filters data and paginates results.  It happens in this order:

1. Read items from the table
2. Apply Filter
3. Return Results

DynamoDB `query` and `scan` operations return up to 1MB of data at a time.  Anything beyond that will be paginated.  You know your results are being paginated if DynamoDB returns a `LastEvaluatedKey` element in your response.

Filters apply *after* the 1MB limit.  This is the critical step that often catches people off-guard.  In your situation, the following is happening:

1. You execute a `scan` operation that reads 1MB of data from the table.
2. You apply a filter to the 1MB response, which results in all of the records in the first step to be eliminated from the response.
3. DDB returns the remaining items with a `LastEvaluatedKey` element, which indicates there is more data to search.

In other words, your filter isn't applying to the entire table.  It's applying to 1MB of the table *at a time*.  In order to get the results you are looking for, you are going to need to execute the `scan` operation repeatedly until you reach the last "page" of the table.

Comment: Hi Seth, But i am not getting Items in any of the 1MB series.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you are facing.  Your initial question says you are getting empty results but later says you are getting results but in a different format.  Can you clarify the problem you're facing?  It would be helpful to see what code or CLI commands you are executing.